# Extract data that is inside a bracket

Tags: python, json

I have been using rapid api to get some data on certain food products and below is an example of the json data i got back. I have been able to get some data such as the ingredients and but where i am struggling is getting the data that are nested inside each other. My question is how would i be able to get for example the data of "amount" which is inside nutrients in python.

```
"ingredients": "Whole Grain Corn, Sugar, Corn Syrup, Corn Meal"


"nutrition": {
    "nutrients": [
       {
            "name": "Calcium",
            "amount": 100.0,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 10.0
       },
       {
            "name": "Carbohydrates",
            "amount": 23.0,
            "unit": "g",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 7.67
       },
```

The way which i was able to get the ingredients was by doing this which worked and printed out the ingredients

```
 ingredients = response.json().get("ingredients")
```

But how would i do the same thing to get specific data inside nutrients such as the "name" carbohydrates?

Answer (score 0):

It's a `list` (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

You can access it by the index (starting at 0). So to get `Carbohydrates` you would do `dictName["nutrition"]["nutrients"][1]["name"]`. To get Calcium you would do  `dictName["nutrition"]["nutrients"][0]["name"]`.

It's probably easiest to just assign  and then loop through with

```
nutrients = dictName["nutrition"]["nutrients"]

for nutrient in nutrients:
    print(nutrient["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to unpack your values one level at a time:

```py
data = response.json() 
nutrition = data.get("nutrition", [])
nutrients = [
    item 
    for item in nutrition.get("nutrients", [])
    if item.get("name") == "Carbohydrates"
]
if nutrients:
    print(nutrients[0])
```

The trickiest part is working with the array. I've used list comprehension to build a new filtered list (some would prefer `filter` function), and then printed an item if the list is non-empty

Comment: `for item in nutrition` should probably be `for item in nutrition["nutrients"]` ?

Comment: @ᴓᴓᴓ, yes, my bad, fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) too, which would look something like this

`carbs = list(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == 'Carbohydrates', response.json()['nutrition']['nutrients']))`

Which is a bit more compact. The output you get is

`[{'name': 'Carbohydrates', 'amount': 23.0, 'unit': 'g', 'percentOfDailyNeeds': 7.67}]`